# Switching between multiple ClearCase regions

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm trying to figure out how can I switch between multiple ClearCase regions without going and modifying the ClearCase properties every time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the latest ClearCase 9.0.1, changing the region does involve changing the ClearCase properties: see "[Assigning a Rational ClearCase host's registry and region](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_rgy_assign_region.htm)".

What you can do (if you don't want to fully switch region through registry/properties) is take advantage of the `-reg/-region` option for some command.

See for instance [`cleartool lsview -reg newtwork-region`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm): you can list views of other regions without changing your current one.

But that remains limited to listing resources (Vobs, Views).
Once you are using commands within a view (lscheckout, checkout, ...), said commands are expected to work within the current region.

You might need to consider registering (`cleartool register`) a view from another region into the registry of this current region.

The alternative, as mentioned in the comments, is to modify the registry, as with this Javascript program [`REGION_SWITCHER.js`](https://www.abs-consulting.co/_faq/answers/clearcase/how_to_switch_clearcase_regions_in_windows.shtml) from 2005.
[Source code](https://www.abs-consulting.com/ftp/TOOLS/REGION_SWITCHER.js.txt).
It modifies:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\Region
```

Comment: Thank you @VonC. I understand we can use the -reg option to list the views but what if i would like to checkout and check-in the files?

Comment: @iab. Exactly: that is the limit of that approach. I have edited the answer with a possible alternative, but I don't see any easy fix to this.

Comment: got it. i will test it out in my environment and i also found this article on the internet to help toggle between the regions by a small program written in java script.                                                          https://www.abs-consulting.co/_faq/answers/clearcase/how_to_switch_clearcase_regions_in_windows.shtml

Comment: @iab. OK. I have included your comment in the answer (with a direct link ot the source of the script) for more visibility.

Comment: In addition to updating the region, is there a way or command that i could use to import the file in tool shortcut options? the thing is we have different configuration files for different regions and if the user would like to create a new in that particular region once switched, the user will have the list of views that are associated to the different region.

Comment: @iab. for different configuration files, it is best to have a view per region, configured to select the right version of said configuration files (for instance in their own branch). That way, the same name can reference a different view per region, already set to select the right files.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if understood your suggestion correctly but you are suggesting to have a view per region registered to their respective region and should select the right configuration file when accessed. right?

Comment: @iab. Yes, that way you have access to the right versions of the config files whenever you switch region.

Comment: i think that helps but how can i create a view respective to that region in the very first place? Once i switch, should i update the configuration file and create view?

Comment: @iab. yes, create one view per region, each with its own config spec (selection rules).

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple regions and share the views between them.  The catch is that if you are in a mixed Unix/Windows environment, Unix can only use Unix views, while Windows can use both.

At my company, we have a Unix region and a Windows region.  If I want to be able to use the same view in both regions, I create it on Unix and then use the Region Synchronizer (look for this on the Administration tab of ClearCase Home Base) to make the view available in Windows.  The tool will take care of registering the view and creating its tag in the second region with the correct path needed to access it.  (We share our Unix view storage locations with Windows using Samba.)

I'm not sure what you need to do to set ClearCase up in the first place so that it's able to see both regions, but as long as you can see both (and you can if the cleartool lsview -reg  works), the Region Synchronizer is the tool you want to use to make it so you can easily check in and check out and otherwise use the view as if it were created in your own region.